# Why am I getting a Fatal error: Call to undefined function prep_connections()?

Tags: php

If you look at the code its clearly defined and public.

```
<?php
class Config {
  public function prep_connections($collection){

  }

  public function get_connctions(){
    require_once('readfile.php');

    $reader = new Readfile();

    $collections = json_decode($reader->read("../../config/database.cfg"));

    foreach($collections as $collection){
       prep_connections($collection);
    }
  }
}

$config = new Config();
$connections = $config->get_connctions();
```

Comment: There is no code at the link you posted.

Comment: You can always indent your code manually - just make sure you post the relevant code and not a novel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it via `$this`, to tell it is in the same/this class

```
$this->prep_connections($collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `prep_connections` outside of the class scope.

You are wanting to call `Config->prep_connections();` but in reality you are calling just `\prep_connections();`.

You should change you line from:

```
prep_connections($collection);
```

To:

```
$this->prep_connections($collection);
```

Or

```
self::prep_connections($collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

`prep_connections()` isn't defined. You have to `include` or `require` the file that defines your functions in order for them to work.